# Clipping/extracting raster from loaded XYZ Tiles basemaps (e.g. Google Satellite)

Tags: qgis, raster, clip, extract

Is there anyway to clip/extract raster from a loaded XYZ Tiles basemap?

I am trying to use Google Satellite imagery, but every time I use the Clip Raster by Extent GDAL tool, I get an error. I am trying to input this in my Graphical Modeler for automation purposes. My current method is to right-click Google Satellite imagery --> export --> select **Save As GeoTiff**, but this procedure is very time-consuming.

Answer (score 4):

You could use GDAL (i.e. gdal_translate) to crop your WMS/XYZ/WMTS rasters.

As an example load the [OpenStreetMap TMS Example](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/gdal/frmts/wms/frmt_wms_openstreetmap_tms.xml) into QGIS (drag & drop XML file into map canvas).

Use gdal_translate to clip the datasource into a virtual raster (VRT):

```
gdal_translate -of VRT -projwin 1774709 6166823 1868433 6112638 "<GDAL_WMS><Service name='TMS'><ServerUrl>https://tile.openstreetmap.org/${z}/${x}/${y}.png</ServerUrl></Service><DataWindow><UpperLeftX>-20037508.34</UpperLeftX><UpperLeftY>20037508.34</UpperLeftY><LowerRightX>20037508.34</LowerRightX><LowerRightY>-20037508.34</LowerRightY><TileLevel>18</TileLevel><TileCountX>1</TileCountX><TileCountY>1</TileCountY><YOrigin>top</YOrigin></DataWindow><Projection>EPSG:3857</Projection><BlockSizeX>256</BlockSizeX><BlockSizeY>256</BlockSizeY><BandsCount>3</BandsCount><UserAgent>QGIS</UserAgent><Cache /></GDAL_WMS>" vienna.vrt
```

Then replace the datasource of the OSM layer with the content of the VRT using the QGIS *changeDataSource* plugin. The big advantage of this method is that you can share the project with others without copying the raster.
[image]