# What are steps to clip Google Satellite Layer from OpenLayers plugin?

Tags: qgis, raster, clip, satellite, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I have imported the Google satellite imagery through the OpenLayers plugin. I want to clip it to a polygon shapefile in Wales.

Is it possible to do this and if not what are the closest alternatives?

Can I use a different satellite layer that can be clipped?

Comment: You could use GDAL to clip your baselayer. More info here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/315637/qgis-data-frame-clipping-for-basemaps/417363#417363 or https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/407355/clipping-extracting-raster-from-loaded-xyz-tiles-basemaps-e-g-google-satellite/407360#407360